# Loading Data From DB Based On Name Passed To Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

Please, I am stuck with this challenge for some hours now. Don’t know where I am getting this wrong.

I have two entities; service_catalog and services. I have a foreign key on services which has a reference to service_catalog. So the idea is that, a service_catalog has many services.

I am trying to get a list of all services based on the service_catalog name passed from the combobox. But I get a null exemption on the serviceList variable. But when I test with a message box, it gave me the id which I taught I could use. But I get the error.

Here is my code. Will appreciate any assistance.

```
//Get catalog name
private service_catalog GetName(string sCatalogname)
{
    using (Model db = new Model())
    {
        return db.service_catalog.FirstOrDefault(s => s.name == Catalogname);
    }
}

//Load the services based on the service_catalog selected
private void comboBoxServices_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    service_catalog data = GetName(comboBoxServices.Text);
    List<service> serviceList;
    if (data != null)
    {
        serviceList = dbHelper.services.Where(s =>s.service_catalog_id == data.service_catalog_id).ToList();
        dataGridViewServices.DataSource = serviceList;

    }
}
```

Error Thrown: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
This line:

```
serviceList = dbHelper.services.Where(s => s.service_catalog_id == data.service_catalog_id).ToList();
```

I appreciate any assistance.

EDIT
from the comment of the OP

serviceList object count is 0 while data object shows

> "{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.service_catalog_BF9EC14C144A9AC84B6F0CB43564996B60E8EA5EA9C2B7D58C0BBE5AE20FC83B}"

Comment: Would you mind adding your exception to your question?

Comment: Ok, and now the Stacktrace please. Which object is null excactly? Could it be, that you did not initialize `dbHelper`?

Comment: I initialize dbHelper in my constructor.

Comment: Ok, put a breakpoint on that line and then check which object is null.

Comment: serviceList object count is 0 while data object shows "{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.service_catalog_BF9EC14C144A9AC84B6F0CB43564996B60E8EA5EA9C2B7D58C0BBE5AE20FC83B}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please put any important info in your question not in in a comment. I did it for you this time

Comment: Noted with thanks.

Comment: could it be your "dbHelper.services" is null, checkout if you initialized your "dbHelper.services" collection in your dbHelper constructor like services = new List<services>() ?